Cannot import UoM list in Odoo 17
I have a list of UoM that need to be imported. I only found the import feature for UoM category, but did not find where I can import a list of UoM.

I did read on this page about UoM. However, it seems to no longer appear on Odoo 17.

So what should I do to be able to import a UoM list on Odoo 17?

Take a look at the base module.  This module imports a CSV file to populate Country State.
create new module and add your data in csv

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
